# Show filename as part of the file icon on MacOS

Tags: macos, icons

Is there a way to make a sort of dynamic icon that will show the filename as part of the icon instead of at the bottom/right of the icon? I am running Snow Leopard.

Comment: I think you'll need a 3rd party app for that.  Icons are images.  If the icon is going to be dynamic, then the icon image would need to be edited to have the filename overlaid for each file.

Comment: That's what I figured. I would even want to do an app like this myself, if there are no existing ones, but I can't figure out what topics I need to look up in order to start.

Comment: Good luck with it.  The only problems i foresee in such an application is that fonts in an image are pretty much useless past a certain image size reduction. Since icons are images, well you know the rest.